# Is there a way to call nonstandard shapes in VBA; using application.caller does not work

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, shapes

I want to assign a macro to shapes in my workbook where the macro assigns a relative hyperlink to the shape that called it.  I tried using application.caller to get the name of the shape to assign the hyperlink but it doesn't work for all shapes, like flow chart shapes.  Any suggestions on how I can get it to work for all shapes?  I get a run time error, item with specified name not found, for all flow chart shapes in my sheet. This code does work for standard shapes like rectangles; but flow chart shapes are required in my document.

```
'Hyperlink to tab "control point log" using text in shape and cell values

Sub Controlpointhyperlink()
Dim rowvar as integer

ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1).Name = "thisshape"

rowvar = Application.WorksheetFunction _
     .Match(ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value & _
     ActiveSheet.Shapes("thisshape").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text, _
     Sheets("Control Point Log").Range("A1:A700"), 0)

With ActiveSheet
     .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:= .Shapes("thisshape"), _
     Address:=ActiveWorkbook.Name & "#" & "'Control Point Log'!$C$" & rowvar
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: is your error here, in this line: `rowvar = Application...`. If so, try to add [this logic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16174772/2143262) to control if each shape has TextRange before you will try to retrieve text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your code, you change name of each shape to 'thisshape' and then add hyperlink to it. I have tried to change your code so the shape reference is set at the beginning of the macro. Then the macro is using this reference. And error check was added before MATCH function call, so if the function dosn't find anything, the mesage box will show up. I have tested it with different shapes including flow chart shapes. Hope this helps.

```
Sub Controlpointhyperlink()

    Dim callerShapeName As String
    callerShapeName = Application.Caller

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim callerShape As Shape
        Set callerShape = .Shapes(callerShapeName)

        Dim findWhat As String
        findWhat = .Range("C2").Value & callerShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text

        Dim findWhere As Range
        Set findWhere = Sheets("Control Point Log").Range("A1:A700")

        Dim rowvar As Double

        Err.Number = 0
        On Error Resume Next

        rowvar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(findWhat, findWhere, 0)
        If (Err.Number = 1004) Then
            MsgBox "No match found for '" & findWhat & "' in range '" & findWhere.Address & "'."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

        Dim addressText As String
        addressText = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "#" & "'Control Point Log'!$C$" & rowvar
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=callerShape, Address:=addressText
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that works for more shapes, but not for shapes that look like 2 overlapping rectangles... that shape still gives me a run time error, item with specified name not found, on the line Set callerShape = .Shapes(callerShapeName).  The name on this type of shape is Flowchart: Predefined Process ###.  This is odd because the macro does work for Flowchart: Magnetic Disk ###.  Additional suggestions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is caused by the Caller. If is Caller of type string then its lenght is limited to 30 characters. Characters above 30 are cut off. So (if possible) rename the shapes with names longer then 30 characters so the new name is shorter then or equal to 30 and the Caller will return complete name of such shapes. This behaviour doesn't depend of shape-type. If you rename normal rectangle so it's name lenght will exceed 30 then the Caller will return only the first 30 characters and Shapes("the_cutted_name") will throw error because shape with this name doesn't exist in shapes collection.