# Check if excel range has shape with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to work through a table downloaded from a 3rd party that uses ticks (shapes) rather than text in the cells. The shapes have no textframe characters. I can't filter the ticks in excel so I want to replace then with text e.g. Yes. Here is my working code but get run time error 438 due to object errors I have tried the excel vba object model but can't get it to work. The VBE doesn't seem to have the Selection.ShapeRange

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange

Here is my code

```
Sub ReplaceShapeswithYes()

' Inserts text where a shape exists

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NumRow As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim NumShapes As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet

NumRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For iRow = 2 To NumRow
    
    Cells(iRow, 10).Select
    'NumShapes = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count ' tried both
    NumShapes = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Count
    
    If NumShapes > 0 Then
    Cells(iRow, 10).Value = "Yes"
    End If
            
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: To iterate the shapes collection while still being able to delete shapes you'll need to go backwards `for s = shapes.count to 1 step -1`. However, figuring out which row a shape is on is more art than science - you'll need `shapes(s).top` and compare it to each row's `top`. It'll work but kind of hacky. Better if you can get the data without shapes. BTW are they definitely shapes (e.g. you can drag them around) or are they text characters in Acii or similar?

Comment: Definitely shapes as I have other code to loop through collection and delete them. I may be onto something with the TopLeftCell property but can't seem to select and then use it to insert the Yes text

Comment: Your answer is appropriate - there is no need (and it's almost never a good idea) to select a cell, just assign its value. Glad you got there.

Answer (score 1):

To get all shapes of a sheet, simply loop over the `Shapes`-collection of the sheet.

The text of a shape can be read with `TextFrame.Characters.Text`, but to be on the save side, you will need to check if a shape has really text (there are shapes that don't have any), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16174772/7599798

To get the position withing a sheet, use the `TopLeftCell`-property.

The following code will copy the text of all shapes into the sheet and delete the shapes:

```
Sub shapeToText(Optional ws As Worksheet = Nothing)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ws.UsedRange.Shapes
        If Not sh.TextFrame Is Nothing Then
            If sh.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                Dim s As String
                s = sh.TextFrame.Characters.Text
                sh.TopLeftCell = s
                sh.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Thomas these shapes don't have any text.

Answer (score 1):

This has done the trick

```
Sub ReplaceShapes()

'Replace all ticks with text

Dim NoShapes As Long
Dim iShape As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim Shp As Shape

Set ws = ActiveSheet

NoShapes = ws.Shapes.Count

For iShape = NoShapes To 1 Step -1:

Set Shp = ws.Shapes(iShape)

Set r = Shp.TopLeftCell

r.Value = "Yes"


Next iShape

End Sub
```