# Rename shape containing specific text

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub RenameShapeNameIfSpecificText()

Dim ppt As Presentation, sld As Slide
Set ppt = ActivePresentation

For Each sld In ppt.Slides

   Dim shp As Shape
   For Each shp In sld.Shapes

      If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "0x" Then
      shp.Name = "Counter"
      End If

   Next shp
Next sld

End Sub
```

I have a 20-slide presentation in which 18 slides have a shape with the text `0x`. I would like to rename those shapes to "Counter".

The above code causes this error: `The Specified Value is out of range`
I suppose the error is being caused due to images being present too.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171219/vba-test-if-shape-contains-a-textframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Use the HasTextFrame property to determine whether a shape contains a text frame before you apply the TextFrame property"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.textframe):

```
Sub RenameShapeNameIfSpecificText()
    Dim ppt As Presentation, sld As Slide, shp As Shape
    Set ppt = ActivePresentation
    
    For Each sld In ppt.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "0x" Then
                    shp.Name = "Counter"
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```